# use foreach while printing category name only once

Tags: php, codeigniter, foreach

I need to show post titles according to their category. but the problem is the design . It has following div structure. I am using PHP.

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="some-class">
  <h1> Category1 name here</h1>
   <ul>
    <li>sds</li>
    <li>sds</li>
    <li>sds</li>
   </ul>
  </div>
<div class="some-class">
  <h1> Category2 name here</h1>
   <ul>
    <li>sds</li>
    <li>sds</li>
    <li>sds</li>
   </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

I know I need to use foreach loop, but don't know in which way
This is the array I am getting.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [category_name] => Getting Started
            [id] => 2
            [question] => GS1
            [answer] => a sd asd asdjasld asd asdasd asd asd asd asdjkalsjd as
 dasd asd asd as das d. as dasd asd as
 asd asd asd asd as das as d.
a sdas d asd as dasd asd asd . asd asss
.a sd asd asd as
            [created] => 2017-02-17 05:26:15
            [slug] => gs1
            [category] => 3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [category_name] => Getting Started
            [id] => 5
            [question] => GS2
            [answer] => sad as d as
            [created] => 2017-02-17 05:48:19
            [slug] => gs2
            [category] => 3
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [category_name] => Buying & Selling
            [id] => 3
            [question] => BS1
            [answer] => sadas dasdas d 
as d
as dasdkas;ldk;laskd; kasd 

as dlask ;ldk; kas;dk asd lka;sdk
            [created] => 2017-02-17 05:47:33
            [slug] => bs1
            [category] => 4
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [category_name] => Buying & Selling
            [id] => 6
            [question] => BS2
            [answer] => as das das d
            [created] => 2017-02-17 05:48:39
            [slug] => bs2
            [category] => 4
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [category_name] => Renting
            [id] => 4
            [question] => rent1
            [answer] => asd asd as das 
            [created] => 2017-02-17 05:48:06
            [slug] => rent1
            [category] => 6
        )

)
```

Comment: have you written query for fetching categories list??

Comment: for better help, Show us the array you are getting.

Comment: one second I will show you array

Comment: @Sarath I have updated the question

Comment: yes, what is ['answer'] ? is it a text ? or need to extract as aray to display in li ?

Comment: @Sarath category name is heading and question is to be echoed in li. currently nothing to do with answer

Comment: Save the last used category in a variable. On each iteration, just check if the category is the same or not. If it isn't, then close the list and div and start a new one. (Don't have time to write an answer now).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First change your QUERY to return the name and category with GROUP BY, try this..

```
   SELECT faq_categories.category_name, GROUP_CONCAT (site_faqs.question) FROM faq_categories JOIN site_faqs ON site_faqs.category = faq_categories.id GROUP BY faq_categories.category_name ORDER BY faq_categories.id ASC
```

And after getting the values as array and try the below code

```
<div class="row">
      <?php foreach( $categoryArr as $category ) { ?>
            <div class="some-class">
              <h1> <?php echo $category['category_name']; ?> </h1>
               <ul>
               <?php $questions = explode (', ', $category['question'] ); // explode the comma seperated question value to array
                     foreach( $questions as $question ){ ?>
                   <li> <?php echo $question; ?> </li>
               <?php } ?>
               </ul>
              </div>
        <?php } ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Why should the OP try this? A good answer includes an explanation, not just a bunch of code. Either way, this answer won't do what the OP asks for.

Comment: @Sarath just check the div structure. if i use then i will get something like this <div class="row">
 <div class="some-class">
  <h1> Category1 name here</h1>
   <ul>
    <li>sds</li>
   </ul>
  </div>
<div class="some-class">
  <h1> Category1 name here</h1>
   <ul>
    <li>sds</li>
   </ul>
  </div>
</div>

Comment: @Sarath I need you in chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136125/discussion-between-sarath-and-prabhjot

Answer (score 1):

Save the last used `category` as `$catt` and we check next time category name is equal or not. 
If not equal means it display the heading and `<li>` also. 
else it display only `<li>` in that heading's sub category.

Thanks for [Magnus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2453432/magnus-eriksson).

Tested:

```
    <div class="row"> 
 <?php
$catt = '';
foreach( $arr as $category ) { 
if($catt != $category){
?>       
 <div class="some-class">
  <h1> <?php echo $category;?></h1>
   <ul>
    <li>sds</li>
    <li>sds</li>
    <li>sds</li>
   </ul>
  </div>
<?php
} else{ ?>
    <ul>
    <li>sds</li>
    <li>sds</li>
    <li>sds</li>
   </ul>    
<?php }
$catt=$category;
 }?>
 </div>
```

Comment: @Nawin *"explanation"* - I see you saying your code works. That is **not** an explanation!

Comment: never feel sorry for your bad english. its not your language.

Answer (score 0):

Hope it will help you.

Steps :

Step 1 : Get category from category table

Step 2 : Get posts from post table based on category id

Code : This is sample code please modify it based on your table and coding

```
<div class="row">
<?php 

 $categories = " SELECT * From Category "  ;
 foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
 $posts = " select * from posts where category = ".$category->id;
 if(count($posts) > 0) {
 ?>

  <div class="some-class">
    <h1> <?php echo $category->name; ?></h1>
    <ul>
    <?php
      foreach ( $posts as $post ) { ?>
      <li> <?php echo $post->title; ?> </li>
    <?php } ?>
   </ul>
 </div>
<?php } } ?>
</div>
```

Note : This just about way you want to use. Please modify it based on your code.